# Duplicate entry '[X]' for key '[Y]' on JPA repository 'save' operation. Saved entity has its key defined already

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, repository

From what I understand, the 'save' function in a JPA repository should automatically do an update if a row with a provided key already exists. However, I'm getting errors that make it seem like it's trying to do a blind `insert` operation instead of an update. I'm at a bit of a loss here.

My entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "inquiry_record")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class InquiryRecordEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "inquiry_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer inquiryId;

    //Lots more fields down below, not important, no other keyed columns
}
```

I have a simple repository:

```
@Repository
public interface InquiryRecordRepository extends CrudRepository<InquiryRecordEntity, Integer> {
}
```

And am trying to do an update on an object like this:

```
@Transactional
public void receiveResponse(SomeUpdateResponse response) {
    log.info("Received responsefor inquiry: {}", safeSerialize(response));

    InquiryRecordEntity inquiry = inquiryRecordRepository.findOne(response.getInquiryId());
    /*...
         A bunch of stuff happens here, determining the value of 'inquiryComplete'.
    ...*/
    if (inquiryComplete) {
        inquiry.setStatus(InquiryRecordEntity.InquiryStatus.CONCLUDED);
        inquiryRecordRepository.save(inquiry);
    }
```

But where I expect it to just overwrite the previous value, it throws an error:

```
[ERROR] o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Duplicate entry '113' for key 'uk_tm_inquiry_id'
[ERROR] c.s.f.c.a.ApiControllerExceptionHandler - org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [uk_tm_inquiry_id]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [uk_tm_inquiry_id]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you reveal some code from "A bunch of stuff happens here, making alterations to the inquiry object."? Looks like the issue may be there.

Comment: Why do you call save in the first place? The entity is managed and its state is thus saved **automatically**

Comment: I can't, but I looked over it again and realized that the inquiry object was never actually changed until that conditional at the end. The code in the middle just determines the value of 'inquiryComplete'

Comment: @JBNizet Are they? I haven't seen anything to indicate such. And it should work regardless, correct? I'm currently working on testing to see if it actually does it in my codebase.

Comment: Just did a test, this is not the case.

Comment: Read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-overview (persistent state of an entity). Read http://vladmihalcea.com/2014/07/30/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-entity-state-transitions/. Or just trust the guy that tells you that because he has 4k+ points in hibernate and 2k+ points in jpa.

Comment: I don't mean to be flippant, but your internet points don't mean that much to me. While what you linked might be useful if I could just spend a few weeks uprooting the entire persistence layer of this project, it's just not a possibility at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Do a quick check on the object identity of the inquiry object you are trying to save.

Just after this line

```
InquiryRecordEntity inquiry = inquiryRecordRepository.findOne(response.getInquiryId());
```

Examine the value of System.identityHashCode(inquiry) - save it as **objId1**

Just after this line

```
inquiry.setStatus(InquiryRecordEntity.InquiryStatus.CONCLUDED);
```

Examine the value of System.identityHashCode(inquiry) - save it as **objId2**

If **objId1** is not the same as **objId2** then you are trying to save another object with the same values, this is why an INSERT is occurring and any unique keys values will throw a ConstraintViolationException. Check where this is happening in the code and fix this bug. It should not be using/creating a different object.

If **objId1** is same as **objId2** then something is wrong with how you are manipulating the state of this object. Check if the id of the inquiry object is getting cleared.